# How can I show the plot points in Oxyplot for a line Graph?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Here is the xaml code to my graph:

```
<oxy:Plot HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="222" 
              Margin="0,49,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="870" 
              Background="Transparent" 
              PlotAreaBorderColor="White" 
              LegendBorder="Transparent"
              Name="viewCountPlot"
              Title="Videos Watched"
              TextColor="White" IsLegendVisible="False" IsManipulationEnabled="False" IsMouseWheelEnabled="False">
        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
            <oxy:DateTimeAxis Name="datetimeAxis" Position="Bottom" MajorGridlineColor="#40FFFFFF" TicklineColor="White" StringFormat="M/d/yy" IntervalType="Days" ShowMinorTicks="False"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries 
                Name="viewCountSeries" 
                Title="Videos Viewed"
                DataFieldX="Date" 
                DataFieldY="Value" 
                Color="#CCFA6800" 
                StrokeThickness="2" 
                TrackerFormatString="Date: {2:M/d/yy}&#x0a;Value: {4}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PlotItems}" MarkerStroke="#FFFDFDFD" />
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:Plot.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Canvas>
                    <Grid Canvas.Left="{Binding Position.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Position.Y}">
                        <Ellipse Fill="White" Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="-6" Y="-6" />
                            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource OrangeTextColor}" Text="{Binding}" Margin="-60 -40 0 0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </oxy:Plot.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
    </oxy:Plot>
```

In the plot Series is there any way to show the plot points as circles or something of that nature?

Here is an example image of what I mean, each plot point has a small circle associated with it:

[image: Plot points are shown]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the linked discussion:

> This should be covered by the `Marker*` properties in the `LineSeries`
>   See examples in the Example browser.

It looks like you have to set `MarkerFill` and `MarkerType`. To show only markers (and no line), set the `Color` to `Transparent`.

```
<oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataPoints}" 
                Color="Transparent" 
                MarkerFill="SteelBlue" 
                MarkerType="Circle" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the Oxyplot forums for those who find this.

https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/528893

Comment: This link is dead