# wpf oxyplot -- change popup when datapoint is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I am using oxyplot with wpf and I want to change the popup if a datapoint gets clicked. [image: OxyplotDataPointClick]

Is it possible to change? I saw a few examples that show how to get the clicked point but nothing about changeing the style.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The popup is called `Tracker` in OxyPlot's source code.
You can define its ControlTemplate in XAML via `OxyPlot.Wpf.PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate` as:

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding SomePlotModel}">
  <oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
       <!-- Put your content here-->
    </ControlTemplate>
   </oxy:PlotView.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
</oxy:PlotView>
```

If each series data need different tracker, then use  `OxyPlot.Wpf.PlotView.TrackerDefinitions`. For example, if your have a LineSeries with `TrackerKey="LineSeriesXyzTrackerKey"`, then defines its tracker as:

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding SomePlotModel}">
  <oxy:PlotView.TrackerDefinitions>
    <oxy:TrackerDefinition TrackerKey="LineSeriesXyzTrackerKey">
      <oxy:TrackerDefinition.TrackerTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
        <!-- Put your content here-->
        </ControlTemplate>
      </oxy:TrackerDefinition.TrackerTemplate>
    <oxy:TrackerDefinition TrackerKey="SomeOtherTrackerKey">
      <oxy:TrackerDefinition.TrackerTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
        <!-- Put your content here-->
        </ControlTemplate>
      </oxy:TrackerDefinition.TrackerTemplate>
  </oxy:TrackerDefinition>
</oxy:PlotView.TrackerDefinitions>
```

The `DataContext` for the `ControlTemplate` is a `TrackerHitResult`, you can view what properties are available here:
https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/PlotController/Manipulators/TrackerHitResult.cs

Some examples:
[How can I show the plot points in Oxyplot for a line Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557334/how-can-i-show-the-plot-points-in-oxyplot-for-a-line-graph)
http://discussion.oxyplot.org/topics/592-wpf-tracker-multiple-value/

Comment: You're the best guy today :-) - Thank you!